# Promise with event in another class

Tags: javascript

I have two files. One called **logic.js** and another **common.js**. In my **logic.js** i have a class with method **getTile()** which contains promise with event

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        this.dbRef.limitToFirst(6).on('child_added', function(data) {
            console.log('child_added called in promise');
            resolve(data);
        });
        this.dbRef.limitToFirst(6).on('child_changed', function(data) {
            console.log('child_changed called in promise');
            resolve(data);
        });
    }.bind(this))
```

And i want to call it in my **common.js** like this

```
database.getTile().then(setTile);
```

but as expected resolving data works only once which means this code does not work. So how can i trigger my **setTile** every time when event triggers in **logic.js** (i can't move out my event from class)?

Comment: *"as expected resolving data works only once"* Well, okay, so you know why it's not working. The behavior is expected because promises are only settled **once**. *"So how can i trigger my setTile every time when event triggers in logic.js"* Don't use a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder any tips what i have to use in this situation?

Comment: This is classic pub/sub (publish/subscribe). Aka "events." Or you could use a boring old callback.

Comment: "*as expected resolving data works only once*" - then you probably also expected that you shouldn't use a promise here?

Comment: You might look into "observable" functionality. Libraries like RxJS make this available if you don't want to roll your own.
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like this:

```
function setTitle(callback) {
    this.dbRef.limitToFirst(6).on('child_added', function(data, callback) {
        callback(data);
    });
    this.dbRef.limitToFirst(6).on('child_changed', function(data, callback) {
        callback(data);
    });
}

setTitle(function(data) {
    console.log("Data received", data);
});
```

Let me know if this satisfies your requirements.